# how to alter the size of Alertbox in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I want to use `AlertBox` in my content page. I am using `AlertBox` in this way.

```
var alertButton1 = new Button { Text = "SimpleWay" };
alertButton1.Clicked += async (sender, e) => 
{
     await DisplayAlert ("Alert", "You are veiwing data", "OK");
};
```

When I run this, It runs successfully and displays data in it's default size. But I want to alter(increase vertically) the size of it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot alter the the size of your `AlertBox` manually. The `AlertBox` automatically sets its size as the data is inserted into the `AlertBox`.

```
     await DisplayAlert ("Alert", "You are veiwing data", "OK");
```

From this change to something like this...

```
     await DisplayAlert ("Alert", <add-a-complete-view>, "OK");
```

Your alert box will automatically adjust itself to the desired and content placing size.